# TypeScript sub class can not inherit parent's method type definition

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I've got a problem with `class` inheritance in `TypeScript`. My sub `class` does **NOT** inherit the method definition of its `parent` class.

```js
class Animal<T = any> {
    public say(a: T) {
        console.log(a);
    }

    walk(s: number) {

    }
}

class Dog extends Animal<string> {
    // a2 has a type of `any` instead of `string`
    say(a2) {

    }
    // s2 recognized as `any`, which should be `number` from parent class definition
    walk(s2) {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a design limitation, parameters of subclass methods are not contextually typed by the base class.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir so in my case, I have to write the `type` of argument again, even if it's declared in the base class? How to handle more complicated argument type then

Comment: Yup, you have to redeclare it. There is a length GH issue discussing this, but I don't have it handy.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir ok, thx for your reply. It's really confusing